# Help please! Installed elementary OS Juno 5 and have no Wifi options

Tags: wifi

I installed elementary OS on my HP Notebook - 15-bw024na for the first time and I can't find a way to connect the wifi. It shows no icons or connections. 
I am new to Linux and was using Windows 10 before. I would really appreciate some help as I have tried everything I could find online to make it work.

I tried installing this: 
https://github.com/smlinux/rtl8723de but did not work.

Tried also the:

```
sudo rmmod athk5
sudo rfkill unlock all
sudo modprobe ath5k
```

And this one among others:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

However, nothing is working so far. I am new to Linux and I am not sure if I am doing things right. Please help :)

[image]

Comment: Can you please confirm again if you see `bcmwl-kernel-source` in AppCenter > Installed (with wired connected).

Comment: Oh, if you did install `bcmwl-kernel-source`, have you tried rebooting afterwards? I can't remember if I needed to when I did it, but it never hurts.

Answer (score 1):

To make WiFi appear in your Network Settings after a fresh Juno 5.0 install, try connecting to the Internet via Ethernet cable first. Then let your system update itself. Reboot. After that you will see the Wifi icon appear in the upper-right menubar panel. Then you can unplug your Ethernet cable and connect via Wifi only.

(Dear elementary OS developers! Please fix this annoying WiFi absence after the fresh elementary OS install! Not everyone has an Ethernet port these days!)

Comment: If you have something you want to share with the devs about anything, please go to https://github.com/elementary and talk to the proper channel. Your participation is much appreciated.